# The need for a ViewModel Provider Factory

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I was wondering why the ViewModel with different parameters in the constructor needs a ViewModel Provider Factory . Why can't a ViewModel be instantiated with a regular constructor `new MyViewModel(parameter1 , parameter2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is stopping you from creating `ViewModel` objects with a `new` keyword. Essentially when there are no constructor parameters provided, that is what Factory Provider does internally, But there are other functionalities wrapped around it. For example lifecycle management. ViewModel in specifically tied to lifecycle constructs such as Fragments and Activities. When things get complicated enough, you would need objects factories for the dependency management.

For the simple example you have given

```
val vm = MyViewModel(height=10, weight=20)
```

It's easier to create those height and weight objects since they are integers but what if it's a complex dependency such as

```
val vm = MyViewModel(repo=MyRepository())
```

And what if `MyRepository` in turns may have dependencies on Retrofit, Room DataBase, Shared Preference.. etc

Now that's where Factory patterns comes into play. Factory patterns can be easily be auto generated using Dependency Injection tools such as Dagger.

Factory patterns are for sophisticated dependency providing mechanism.

Comment: the reason why I asked is because one time , my app crashed if I instantiated the ViewModel like that , after googling I found that I had to create the ViewModel Provider Factory .

Comment: When you create the object using new keyword, you're not providing life cycle information... That's why it crashes...

Comment: But isn't this the same in kotlin ? `MyViewModel(height=10, weight=20)`  , would it crash in this case ?

Comment: Yes it does work for me on viewmodel lib version 2.1.0-alpha04